# What Scala-oriented game frameworks exist?

Tags: scala

I'm looking into Scala game development, and wondering if there are any game frameworks oriented towards it, rather than Java.

Java has [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) and [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/), but they do not take advantage of Scala features.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/scage/ Google is your friend you know

Comment: Note: If you'd like to downvote it would be great if you left a comment detailing why you did it

Comment: ^Lack of research is why I would downvote.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048801/is-there-any-game-engine-in-scala

Comment: That question linked question was asked in June of 09 ... over 3 years ago.

Comment: Lack of research? Hardly, I have a specific question and the linked SO question does not answer it.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't much in the way of game specific frameworks/engines. What does exist is largely immature though can help provide a higher level of abstraction for rendering:

- Sgine - http://www.sgine.org - This one has been undergoing a rewrite for a long period of time, I woulnd't count on this one for anything practical anytime soon. I looked at this early on in creating my game, and while it looked extremely productive for tiny projects, I decided not to use it after finding  too many core problems in my mind to justify it's use in anything substantial.
- Simplex3D - http://code.google.com/p/simplex3d - Provides math, data binding and rendering libraries, I haven't used this one, but it looks solid for what it provides.
- Scage - https://github.com/dunnololda/scage - 2D only, I have little familiarity with this project, it seems tailored to small projects, the network api looks neat though.

I've built an engine directly on top of LWJGL over the past year. In retrospect it seems to have been a good idea. I honestly can't imagine using anything but Scala at this point (though except maybe Rust one day in the far future). I simply couldn't stand to use something as unproductive as Java or C++ again.

Not that it's a great measure of size, but my game including the engine/framework is approx 440 scala classes.

A side note: The game libraries suffer from similar problems to Scala libraries as a whole, especially in their (and in some way Scala's) relative immaturity, they're all written in their own interpretation of how Scala code should be written (something which is very diverse amongst scala libraries).

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what specific features of scala you'd like to see in a game lib.  My gut-feel says it is better to use a well known and fully functional java engine than a new scala one.   Using java libs out of the box is one of the "specific features" of scala ;-).

A while back, I wrote a small game in Scala using the [GTGE](http://www.goldenstudios.or.id/products/GTGE/).  I can really recommend it.  The scala source code is on [launchpad](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~willem-duminy/+junk/boogaloo/files) if you'd like to take a look before using it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to keep up with this now will be to peruse (and update) the [awesome list](https://github.com/ScalaGameDev/awesome-scala) on [ScalaGameDev](https://github.com/ScalaGameDev/). The site also aims to host discussion related to Scala game development using (currently) [gitter](https://gitter.im/ScalaGameDev/incubator), though this was just created..